# Moderate/Hide a Facebook Comment using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

We are using the Graph API to read the comments appearing on a Page (e.g. the comments on http://facebook.com/Nike are accessible by crawling https://graph.facebook.com/Nike/posts&access_token=my_access_token).

Question: I see an `HTTP DELETE` can be used to delete a comment; is there an API to moderate it (e.g. mark it as `is_private`, something reversible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately its not possible at this time :(
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/439078329445665?browse=search_506da06b6babc7479209814

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for linking to the feature request.

Answer (score 1):

By now it is possible to hide facebook comments. The `can_hide` field will show you if you (e.g. the user/page associated with the given access token) is allowed to hide the comment. `is_hidden`, well, that one is pretty self-explanatory.

So first, use a `GET` request to see if the comment is already hidden, and if you can hide it:

```
[comment_id]?fields=is_hidden,can_hide
```

If allowed and necessary, you can use a `POST`request with `is_hidden=true` to actually hide it.

[Read the docs for more information.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/comment)