# How to know if a comment on a page post is hidden in Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hidden, facebook-comments

We are looking for a way to find out, if a comment is hidden on a story on a page feed. We are using the Graph API to get the comments: [story_id]/comments with an Admin Access Token. Facebook tells us if we can delete the comment. However, there is no "is_hidden" flag or something.

Is there any other way to find out if the comment is hidden/marked as spam?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm PHP Developer, we have also used Facebook Graph API many times.
As per my expertise, I think we cannot fetch/identify only hidden/spam comments.
But yes you can get the comments for only particular user if you want.

For example:
1.) Get id of a fanpage with public graph data: http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola - thumsup has 507267189335315.
2.) Get ThumsUp's "like plugin" iframe display directly with some modified params: http://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=40796308305
3.) Now check the page sources, there are a lot of fans with links to their profiles, where you can find their profile ids or nicknames
4.) If you are interested only in profile ids use the graph api again - it will give you profile id directly

I hope you will find my answer appropriate.
If you are getting some other solution, please share

Thanks,
Shreyas

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes there seems to be no way to get the hidden comments with Graph API at the moment. The only way is to go with FQL..

However, I don't know how your example may help me here.

Answer (score 0):

By now, finding out if a comment is hidden can be achieved via the `is_hidden` flag.

[More detailed answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116847/moderate-hide-a-facebook-comment-using-graph-api/42471267#42471267)

[Facbook API docs for comment endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/comment)